# Why do I get "Schema-validation: missing sequence [SEQ_BANDO]" error?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, tomcat, entity

when i start my tomcat,I get this error: "Schema-validation: missing sequence [SEQ_BANDO]".
This is my entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="bando.findAll", query= "SELECT b FROM bando b")
public class Bando extends BaseBean implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="BANDO_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="SEQ_BANDO", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="BANDO_ID_GENERATOR")
private Long id;
```

and so going on...
Is there something I'm missing?

Forgot to add important notes...I'm using postgresql and I got a bunch of other entity classes,it works fine for them

Comment: You don't have SEQ_BANDO in your database.

Comment: Oh...I thought hibernate would generate the seq for me...Thank you for your answer

Comment: Ah. Are other sequences generated?